# Difficulty in executing basic OpenCV example on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, osx-lion

System Information: Mac OSX 10.7.3

I am trying to execute basic opencv example. The program is getting compiled but when I try to execute I receive this error msg:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libx264.118.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libavcodec.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Before it was working fine. But yesterday I just reinstalled my Xcode 4.3 version and I don't know why suddenly I get this error for this example.

Can someone please help me with that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself. So either try simply this:

```
sudo port -nR upgrade --force ffmpeg
```

because I think these lib files mentioned below may belongs to ffmpeg and maybe ffmpeg package might have broken.

```
libx264.118.dylib
libavcodec.dylib
```

Or you can do this for all outdated ports. It will most probably fix all the bugged ports

```
sudo port outdated
sudo port -nR upgrade --force outdated
```